# Asymptotic behaviour of the o.d.e $\dot{x'}(t)= Bh(x'(t))$ from the asymptotic behaviour of an o.d.e $\dot{x}(t) = h(x(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the asymptotic behaviour of an o.d.e $\dot{x}(t) = h(x(t))$ where $h:\Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^d$ is it possible to tell the asymptotic behaviour of the o.d.e $\dot{x'}(t)= Bh(x'(t))$ where $B$ is a $d \times d$ matrix. I cannot directly analyze the latter o.d.e

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\dot{x}(t) = h(x(t))$ has an equilibrium, let's say at $0$, with linearization $\dot{x}(t) = H x(t)$ where $H$ is a matrix.  Then the linearization of $\dot{x}'(t) = B h(x'(t))$ also has an equilibrium there, 
with linearization $\dot{x}'(t) = BH x'(t)$.  From the asymptotics of solutions of your first equation near $0$ as $t \to +\infty$ and $t \to -\infty$ you may be able to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $H$, and thus $H$ itself, and then the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $BH$ tell you about solutions of your new equation near $0$.

Comment: I did say **linearization**.  If the system is hyperbolic, its behaviour near the equilibrium point is determined by the linearization.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, did not check earlier properly, will check.

Comment: Actually the o.d.e is $\dot{\theta}(t) = \left(\frac{A}{\theta_{x_0}(t)} - B\right)\theta(t)$
where $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices and $\theta_x(.)$ is the $x$-th component of $\theta(.)$.